# split an equation with multicols on

Tags: compiler-errors, latex, equation, multicol

I would like to split my large equation in two column. But my file fails to compile when I try to use `\{amsmath}` and then split, multline, etc...
The error says: Package amsmath Error:

> \begin{multline} allowed only in paragraph mode. \begin{multline}

Does someone knows how to split a large equation while using `multicols`?

Here my file:

```
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{multicols}{2}

\begin{equation}
\begin{multline}
E(x_0, y_0)=  \int^{+\infty}_{-\infty} \ , exp \left( az \bigg[ \frac{ax_0}{3z} + \frac{y^2-2y_0 y}{2z} \bigg] \right) \cdot E(x,y)dxdy
 \end{multline}
\label{Equation_1}
\end{equation}

\end {multicols}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error tells you that you cannot use `multline` in mathmode (which is entered when you use an `equation` block). The `multline` environment already implies mathmode.

When I remove the `equation` block it works. Remember you have to add a `\\` to actually use multiple lines in your equation.

Resulting code:

```
\begin{multicols}{2}

\begin{multline}
E(x_0, y_0)=  \int^{+\infty}_{-\infty} \ , exp \left( az \bigg[ \frac{ax_0}{3z} + \frac{y^2-2y_0 y}{2z} \bigg] \right)\\ \cdot E(x,y)dxdy
 \end{multline}
\label{Equation_1}

\end{multicols}
```